# Carousel accessibility best practices

Tags: interaction-design, accessibility, carousel

I am trying to design a new carousel component but struggling to figure out any accessibility best practices.

These are some of the things I am trying to think about:

**Pagination indicators**

1. Should these be clickable
2. If clickable to they have to meet minimum touch target areas (44px), or if there is another form of pagination such as icon buttons with arrows does this not matter?

**Responsive design**

1. Should my designs / interactions for WEB and APPS differ?

If anyone has any knowledge around best practices I would appreciate it!

Comment: Good info from w3.org here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/), there are four guidelines for making carousels accessible:

1. **Structure: Use semantic structure for the carousel to support proper
   function of assistive technology.** This means that your developers should code it properly so that screen readers and other devices can control it.
2. **Functionality: Add functionality to display and announce carousel items.** Make sure that those who are using screen readers understand that the content is changing as the items change.
3. **Animations: Add a transition animation between items and ensure users can stop and resume it.** Animations help sighted users perceive change;  thus it [reduces cognitive load](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/minimize-cognitive-load/). The user must be able to pause and control every item, as reading speeds differ. [Other animation guidelines](https://www.boia.org/wcag2/cp/2.2.2) require giving users the ability to pause and stop animation to prevent seasickness and other vestibular disorders.
4. **Styling: Style the carousel to make sure it’s usable and readable by everyone.** Make sure text doesn't become too small to read on mobile, as an example.

Other accessibility considerations:

- Let the user know how many items there are in the carousel, and which item they're perceiving; this is especially helpful for screen reader users. Pagination can be helpful (such as showing **1/5**). Dots are sometimes easy to miss on a busy background.
- It is more accessible to show forward/backward controls at all times vs. on hover.

**Should my designs / interactions for WEB and APPS differ?**

Yes. Per [Nielsen/Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/designing-effective-carousels/), do not auto-forward carousel items on mobile. Remember that swiping is not available to all users on mobile (think of a person who can only use one hand, either temporarily or permanently) so you might want to provide a secondary way for your mobile users to interact with the carousel. They should absolutely be of a minimum touch target size.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the interest you want to give to the content, a carousel of a photographer who usually prefers not to touch the dimensions of their images is very different from a carousel of an online store, which only intends to sell.

For this second case, the most common option is to vary the content and format according to the device type.

A practical example, [costco.com](https://www.costco.com/), (or any large online store)

Desktop version:

[image]

Mobile version:

[image]

The page indicators maintain the same dimension, which in the mobile version offers enough size to click.

---

<sub>*Side note: to be honest, it's something that only the designer perceives. I used to make three images for the same carousel for a client: desktop, tablet, and mobile. They realized this two years later. Since then I usually send emails with each change made, and in general, they continue without realizing it.*</sub>

Comment: A note on you side note: Well, you could say it is experienced but not realized. That they don't realize the differences in the desktop and mobile images is a sign that you did your job very well. The experience between different devices should be seamless and if someone notices a difference very easily that would mean there is something wrong.

Comment: Very good appreciation, I will take it into account  . Although many factors come into play, one of them, perhaps the most important, is the constant vindication that we designers must make about the value of our profession and the effort that the work carried out entails. Note that in my example, the client only sees the work done by a single image (not three).